# Should I scrape the paper backing from vinyl flooring off a concrete floor to prep for tiling?

Tags: flooring, ceramic-tile, vinyl

Once the flooring is pulled up is it necessary to remove the dense paper layer which ultimately glued the linoleum to concrete.  If it is not necessary to remove do I rough up the surface to make a more adhesive surface?

Or will thinset adhere to the dense paper layer?  This paper layer has been exposed on my kitchen floor for over 3 years with spills.  It does absorb but no deterioration.  Help! thank you for the expert advice.

Comment: I edited the formatting of your post to make it readable, and added information about your question to the title -- better titles get more attention. Welcome to the site!

Comment: I use a wide blade scraper with a long handle to scrape up the backing, if the original linoleum is pre 1970 era you may want to have it tested for asbestos. I like to remove the backing so there is a solid bond but have seen others lay over the top and the end result looked good but I am not sure if it will last as long but in the few cases I have seen without looking at those jobs again years later I can't say Absoutly one way is better than another. I do know with a solid base of concrete , thinset and tile the tile is less likely to crack if a heavy item is dropped on the tile.

Answer (score 4):

I would not attempt to bond mortar to fuzzy paper. The resulting bond will only be as strong as the paper itself, which isn't good.

Use a combination of grinding tools, moisture, and scrapers to get the concrete reasonably clean before installing tile.

Comment: I agree , I have seen it done but don't know if it lasted stripping / grinding is the way to go.